# Seemed be lost everything after installed ubuntu in my windows 7 computer

Tags: 10.10

I was trying to install ubuntu in my windows 7 with separate partition, and I made a CD for ubuntu 10.10 and installed into my computer. But after I installed ubuntu I don't see any option for windows 7. It seems like I lost everything my important documents. Is there any way I could get back my files. Please help me out.

Comment: You could only lost the Windows partition if you selected to remove the existing partitions, you should not have proceeded if you didn't understood the questions. As for the recovery, try to get in touch with someone more skilled Ubuntu, he may be able to use testdisk or other recovery tools and recover some of your data.

Answer (score 2):

You could have read something like this before you tried to install Ubuntu as dual boot : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot
 If you installed Ubuntu in separate partition then you can access your windows files from ubuntu. You can find all the partitions(including windows) from the 'places' menu on the top panel

Answer (score 1):

Boot Ubuntu, open a terminal and enter the command: sudo update-grub 
This command will create the file grub.cfg which will update your grub-menu.
Then Reboot. Now Windows 7 should appear in the boot-menu.
If it doesn't help you can mount your windows partition from ubuntu to access your files.